# In .Rprofile why doesn't load(".RData") work, but it will work in a R script called by .Rprofile?

Tags: r

When I try to load a workspace using **load(".RData")** in the **.First** function in **.Rprofile**, it does nothing. It does work if I execute that same function in **MKS Startup.R** which is called by **.Rprofile**.

Other commands such as library() do work in .First. Why doesn't load()?

```
.First <- function(){

library(R.utils)

cat("\n------------------------------------------\n\n ")

cat("\n   Personal RProfile!\n\n ")

cat("\n   Working Directory: ")
setwd( "C:/Users/Mike/Documents/R Projects")

utils::loadhistory(".Rhistory")   # this works!

load(".RData")                    # does not work!
base::load(".RData")              # does not work either!

cat(getwd())
cat("\n\n")

source("MKS Startup.R")

}
```

Comment: `load` will load objects into the environment in which it is called. So the object will be lost once `.First` exits. (Try `print(exists(<object name>))` after your `load` calls for some `<object name>` known to exist in `.RData`.)

Comment: > ls()
[1] "apple"  "banana" "grape"  "peach" 
> print(exists("apple"))
[1] TRUE